# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005

Tags: c#, asp.net

i didn't find Microsoft word document under the "Control Panel - Administrative Tools - Component Services - Computers - My Computer - DCOM Config" then how to grant the permissions for microsoft word and excel

Comment: what is that ? what to do with asp.net ? where did you get this message and how ?

Answer (score 1):

Read out load this article, and learn why you should never attempt it even,

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

Answer (score 0):

Using Office interop in a server-scenario (like ASP.NET, Windows Service etc.) is NOT supported by MS - see http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2

Additionally there have been several security-related changed since Windows Vista which basically make it really hard to do anything "desktop-like" in a Windows Service (IIS/ASP.NET is just a special case of Windows Service in this regard).

There are several libraries (free and commercial) to deal with Office files (without Office Interop).

MS provides the free OpenXML SDK V 2.0 - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854%28office.14%29.aspx (newer formats only like DOCX, XLSX etc.).

*Excel*

Another free option see http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/OpenXML.aspx (XLSX only)

IF you need more like handling older Excel versions (like XLS, not only XLSX), rendering, creating PDFs, formulas etc. then there are different free and commercial libraries like [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) (free, XLSX  only), [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) (free, XLSX only), [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx), [SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/), [LibXL](http://www.libxl.com/) and [Flexcel](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp) etc.

*Word*

- [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx)
- [Gembox.Documents](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/overview)